# Connect the regions using the PRISM library

Tags: wpf, prism

Please help. Is it possible to connect all the regions with PRISM? For example I have three regions and they have three Views. The first region has a menu with buttons. The second and third regions for example have RichTextBox. How can I send commands from the first region to the second and third region by pressing buttons? Thank you.

Comment: Read up on `IEventAggregator`.  It's part of PRISM.  You can get it injected into your views and view-models

Answer (score 0):

The prism library offers this feature out of the box and is well documented. All you need is the [Event Aggregator](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/event-aggregator.html) and your own PubSubEvent published in one region and subscribed in the other.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm starting to read about Event Aggregator. I saw Brian Lagunas use attributes to bind views, or maybe I misunderstood his video.

Comment: Are you thinking about [Navigation Parameters](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/passing-parameters.html)? Those do indeed work for passing information from one page to another. I don't know if that is what you were looking for instead? if it's just to pass an id or a field value, that indeed would be the best approach. The Event aggregator is more for services talking to each other.

Comment: In any case, thanks for your help.  I will try EventAggregator.